# Views, group by first letter as rest export (Alphabet/Glossary listing?)

Tags: views, 8

Is there a way to group results by the first letter of their title in a REST export per the screenshot?

[image]

My first thought would be perhaps extending `Serializer` to process the results, at the expense of pagination. In my case, it is only about 100 records, and won't be paginated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but I came up with this:

```
/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "serializer_glossary",
 *   title = @Translation("Serializer Glossary"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes results and groups them by first letter, for small result lists only."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class SerializerGlossary extends Serializer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $rows = [];

    foreach ($this->view->result as $row) {
      $entity = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
      $title = $entity->label();
      $first_letter = Unicode::strtoupper($title[0]);
      $rows[$first_letter][] = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
    }

    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }

    return $this->serializer->serialize(['results' => ['items' => $rows, 'totalCount' => count($this->view->result)]], $content_type);
  }
}
```

[image]

I am open to other answers if there is a better way.

The frontend is processing this via ReactJS to do the screenshot in the original question. The reason it is wrapped with 'results' and then 'items' is from a request from the frontend developer to have it structured that way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with REST export so I don't know how it might affect your case, but I don't see why it wouldn't work if you set up your fields right.

### Use `Trim this field` and `Grouping field Nr.1`

1. Create the usual Views of your content showing the Title, Body summary or whatever is applicable in your case
2. Create another **Title** field or the one you want to group your Views by, even if you already have it from the first step.
3. Set that field to
   **Don't!** Create a label
   **Exclude from display**
   **Formatter** **Plain text**
   **Rewrite results:**

   - **Trim this field to a maximum number of characters**
   - Maximum number of characters **1**
   - Untick “Trim only on a word boundary”
   - Untick “Add "…" at the end of trimmed text”

   This is how you get the Title field to only display the first letter.
4. Now edit the **Format: Settings** and under the **Grouping field Nr.1** select that field (mind the order of fields since you'll have two)
5. **Add Sorting criteria** by **Title** field
6. Setup your REST exporter if you haven't already

Comment: In true Drupal fashion, Views Rest exports don't provide the option to group by a field.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue at drupal.org to [Add grouping to views REST Serializer formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3251937#comment-14307183).

Check out the latest patch there, that allows to enable the grouping on REST views serializer formatter.

After activating the patch, you could do the regular grouping, as @prkos described in his answer.

If you do not want to patch the core, alternatively you can create a custom views style:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\style;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer;

/**
 * The style plugin for grouped serializer output format.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "serializer_grouped",
 *   title = @Translation("Serializer Grouped"),
 *   help = @Translation("Provides possibility to groups serialized results."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class SerializerGrouped extends Serializer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $usesGrouping = TRUE;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $rows = [];

    // Group the rows according to the grouping instructions, if specified.
    $sets = $this->renderGrouping(
      $this->view->result,
      $this->options['grouping'],
      TRUE
    );
    $groups = $this->renderGroupingSets($sets);

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
      foreach (Element::children($group) as $key) {
        $group_id = trim(strip_tags((string) $group['#title']));
        $rows[$group_id][] = $group[$key];
      }
    }

    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }

    return $this->serializer->serialize($rows, $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function renderRowGroup(array $rows = []) {
    return $rows;
  }

}
```